# Cant get program to run correctly Python/Qt/PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

So i am just starting out using Qt4 and pyqt to convert the code to python and so on. I am trying to create a timer of sorts but that doesn't really matter. I've created the gui in Qt and converted it to python code, added a few things to get the code running, but when i run it i still just get a blank window, none of the buttons of boxes that i created are showing up. any ideas??

thanks

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8


def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


class Ui_Dialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def _init_(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(160, 183)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.countInput = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.countInput.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("countInput"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.countInput, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.timeView = QtGui.QLCDNumber(Dialog)
        self.timeView.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhDigitsOnly)
        self.timeView.setDigitCount(5)
        self.timeView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("timeView"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.timeView, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.startButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.startButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("startButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.startButton, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.stopButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.stopButton.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.stopButton.setDefault(True)
        self.stopButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("stopButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.stopButton, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.progressLbl = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.progressLbl.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.progressLbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.progressLbl.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("progressLbl"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.progressLbl, 4, 0, 1, 2)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.startButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Start", None))
        self.stopButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Stop", None))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Dialog()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def _init_(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

You are missing the double underscores for the init, so yours isn't getting called.
It should be:

```
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
```